# Is it possible to style a table with round corners in CUBA Platform?

Tags: css, cuba-platform, cuba

I want to make rounded edges for my table. Just tried to modify `v-table-border-radius`. It did just make the border round, so it looks like that:

[image]

What could I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following style resolves the issue:

```
.v-table {
  background: transparent;

  .v-table-header-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .v-table-body {
    $background-color: $v-table-background-color or valo-table-background-color();
    background: $background-color;
  }
}
```

Add it to the theme extension, e.g. in the `hover-ext.scss` file.

[image]

It is also worth adding bigger padding for the first column caption, e.g.:

```
.v-table-header-cell:first-child:not(.c-grouptable-group-divider-header) .v-table-caption-container {
  padding-left: round($v-unit-size / 2);
}
```

[image]

Pay attention that the `v-table-border-radius` variable is used to add border radius to table **header** and **footer**. **Footer** is hidden until you use *aggregation* with `aggregationStyle="BOTTOM"`. In order to have bottom border radius without footer, I'd recommend adding a custom style name to a table that adds bottom border radius instead of adding it globally in case you'll use **BOTTOM** aggregation, e.g.:

`<table stylename="bottom-border-radius" ...>` with the following style implementation:

```
.bottom-border-radius .v-table-body {
  @if $v-table-border-radius > 0 {
    border-radius: 0 0 $v-table-border-radius $v-table-border-radius;
  }
}
```

---

Upd: improved styles for screen background color that differs from table background color.
Upd2: Added custom styles for bottom border radius.

Comment: Hey glebfox, thanks for your solution! I tried it, but I still have the problem. My background is grey, so I always see the white edges of my white table, but I need them to be rounded like the border.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the gray background. Updated answer.

Comment: I just realized that my table has round edges on top, but not at the bottom. Do you have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: The `v-table-border-radius` variable is used to add border radius to table **header** and **footer**. **Footer** is hidden until you use *aggregation* with `aggregationStyle="BOTTOM"`. I've updated my answer to cover this case.